# DELETE default ubuntu user

Tags: server

I am new to this. Should I delete user ubuntu and Create new one. As everyone knows the username and they can try to login. What's say?

This a ec2 of AWS

Comment: Is this for an Ubuntu Server instance on Amazon EC2? Generally, you specify your own account names on self-installed systems 

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version. The official distro doesn't have `ubuntu` user.

Comment: There is no user called @ubuntu@ That is the name of the OS. The default user is the one you created during the install.

Comment: Thats a ec2 of AWS

Comment: On EC2, the default user is indeed called 'ubuntu'. You can delete that user if you would like, but only after creating another and confirming that you can log in. More importantly, however, you absolutely must tune your SecurityGroup for this instance to restrict ssh connections to only work from known "safe" IP addresses. This is outside of the scope of AskUbuntu, and you are likely to find good help on how to do this on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @JamesS. I believe it is "The default user name is determined by the AMI that was specified when you launched the instance."

Comment: Yes. In the case of Ubuntu AMIs, that username is 'ubuntu'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an EC2 question, the short answer is “No, you do not need to delete the default user”.

There are two primary reasons for this:

1. Port 22 *should be* limited via the security policy that the EC2 instance(s) are using. If SSH is open to `0.0.0.0` then something needs to be changed. Immediately.
2. Even if people know the account name, they will need the `.pem` private key file that you have associated with the instance(s).

You certainly can change or remove accounts from EC2 instances, but you shouldn’t need to.

Comment: Point #1 is the really important one. SecurityGroup settings on EC2 are not hard to understand, but they are definitely different from what someone might expect if they are used to administering systems outside of EC2.

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to delete the ubuntu user though?

Comment: @CaffeineAddiction there are no reasons to keep the initial account if you really want it gone. Just be sure to create a new account that has `sudo` permissions beforehand if you wish to administer the VM 